# Changed keyboard map reverts back after short time

Tags: x11, xkb

I use:

```
        xkbcomp "$DISPLAY" - |                                                        
            # Menu key = mouse button                                                 
            # key <COMP> {         [ Menu ] };                                        
            # =>                                                                      
            # key <COMP> {         [ Pointer_Button2 ] };                             
            perl -pe '/key <COMP>/ && s/\[.*\]/ [ Pointer_Button2 ]/' |               
            sed -e '/interpret KP_/,/};/d' |                                          
            # Replace numpad , with .                                                 
            sed -e 's/ KP_Separator / period /' |                                     
            xkbcomp - "$DISPLAY" 2> >(grep -v 'No symbols defined for')
```

to fix up my keyboard.

That has worked great. But now this reverts back to the original layout after some minutes. I can then run the above again, but again it reverts back after some time.

What could be causing that?

Is there a way I can cause X.org to log that, so I can catch the culprit?

I run KDE on Ubuntu 20.04.